# Unix delete all folders in a directory with a specific name

Tags: unix, find, rm

Hi I've got lots of folders with the name "@eaDir" all across one of my disks and I'd like to search through, find all of them and delete them and their contents.

I know this is probably a combination of the find and rm command but I can't quite figure them out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
find . -type d -name '@eaDir' -print0 | xargs -rt0 rm -rv
```

Here's the same thing but using explicit long options for `xargs`:

```
find . -type d -name '@eaDir' -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty --verbose --null rm -rv
```

(using long options is always a good idea if you're writing scripts that will need to be maintained/reviewed by other people)

But before anything else:

```
man find
man xargs
```

Comment: Why using a non-standard argument to find, `find . -type d -name '@eaDir' -exec rm -rv {} \;` is fine, no ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine too. The difference is that with `-exec` option `find` will spawn a `rm` process for each directory found. With `xargs` the argument list for `rm -rv` is built, and then `rm -rv [argument list here]` is invoked once.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/the/disk -type d -name "@eaDir" -delete
```

Notice that the order here is fundamental: quoting the manpage,

> Warnings:  Don't  forget that the find command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to delete everything below the starting points you specified.

So, *as always*, first try your `find` command with `-print`, then, when you checked that everything works fine, replace it with `-delete`. Notice that `-delete` implies `-depth`, so, to do meaningful testing with `-print`, you should explicitly specify it in the expression:

> When testing a find command line that you later intend  to  use  with -delete,  you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid later surprises.

Comment: Right, but i'd be wary to use and recommend `-delete`. It has the potential to cause a disaster putting it in the wrong place/order.

Comment: @dschulz: yes, the order thing here is fundamental, if you put it before the `-name` it will happily erase everything under the specified root. On the other hand, the usual rule about mass deletion and shell scripting applies here: *first* test with `-print` (`echo`), *then* put `-delete` (`rm`) in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Goto root folder or directory and execute the following command:

```
find . -path '*/@eaDir/*' -delete -print && find . -path '*/@eaDir' -delete -print
```

This should work for you.